# Pass argument in eclipse scons building

Tags: eclipse, scons

Hi I have created a Makefile project in eclipse and exported the source code with an existing SConstruct file that build the project from cmd. I am accepting two arguments in the SConstruct as -

```
socns -Q mode=debug toolchain=x86
```

In the build setting I have given the

```
command = scons -Q mode=debug toolchain=x86
```

But the argument is never accepted in the SConstruct file. Please tell me how to pass the two argument while building eclipse project with scons scripts and two argument passed.

```
#the buidling mode that should be passed by the use!

mode = ARGUMENTS.get('mode')

if not ( mode in ['debug','release']):

    print "ERROR: mode must be debug/release"

    Exit(1)



#the toolchain that should be passed by the user

#can be either x86 or arm

toolchain = ARGUMENTS.get('toolchain')

if not ( toolchain in ['x86','arm']):

    print "ERROR: toolchain must be x86/arm"

    Exit(1)
```

Comment: What are the results you are seeing? Is it displaying one of those errors?

Comment: Yes. It is giving the errors "ERROR: mode must be debug/release" ... Now I am trying to define the variables in an external .py file and trying to read them from the SConstruct itself during run-time. I saw that it is possible. Do u know how to do that??

Comment: Its hard to tell if its passing in the wrong value for mode and toolchain, or if they're empty. Try printing the value in the error printout. You may need to use ARGUMENTS.get('mode', default='someDefaultValue')